# Payment Gateway for a cloned Stellar blockchain network

Tags: payments

We have cloned/forked a new blockchain network using Stellar. It has some API documentation that we can create a payment gateway as well, however, we are looking for an open-source payment gateway the same as [StellarPay](https://stellarpay.io/documentation/custom/).

Is there one to fork and work with?
I just throw in the Stellar network hence I'm sorry if it's a silly question.

Thanks in advance.